# JEP286 - Use of Indexes in enhanced for-loop

Tags: java, java-10

I was reading up the documentation for Local-Variable Type Inference at the below Open JDK link.

http://openjdk.java.net/jeps/286

One thing caught my eye - "**indexes in the enhanced for-loop**". I looked up SO and don't see where indexes in enhanced for loop are discussed. My understanding so far has been that indexes are only allowed in traditional for loops (Clearly, i am missing something).

Can you please provide some examples for use of indexes in enhanced for-loop?

**Goals**

> We seek to improve the developer experience by reducing the ceremony
>   associated with writing Java code, while maintaining Java's commitment
>   to static type safety, by allowing developers to elide the
>   often-unnecessary manifest declaration of local variable types. This
>   feature would allow, for example, declarations such as:
>
> ```
> var list = new ArrayList<String>();  // infers ArrayList<String>
> var stream = list.stream();          // infers Stream<String>
> ```
>
> This treatment would be restricted to local variables with
>   initializers, **indexes in the enhanced for-loop**, and locals declared in
>   a traditional for-loop; it would not be available for method formals,
>   constructor formals, method return types, fields, catch formals, or
>   any other kind of variable declaration.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you further look at the [style guidelines](http://openjdk.java.net/projects/amber/LVTIstyle.html) linked in the same document, you can find a good suggestion of using iterator under "Examples" with the local variable such as:

> ```
> void removeMatches(Map<? extends String, ? extends Number> map, int max) {
>     for (var iterator = map.entrySet().iterator(); iterator.hasNext(); ) {
>         var entry = iterator.next();
>         if (max > 0 && matches(entry)) {
>             iterator.remove();
>             max--;
>         }
>     }
> }
> ```

Further for the indexes part specifically, you can also do something like:

```
void removeMatchesIndexes(List<? extends Number> list, int max) {
    for (var i = 0; i < list.size(); i++) {
        var entry = list.get(i);
        if (entry.intValue() > max) {
            list.remove(entry);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

This is referring to the variable declared withing the enhanced for loop, such as:

```
var elements = new Arraylist<String>();
// Fill the list
for (var element : elements) {
    // element is type String
}
```